# Facebook - how to Like a specific post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a twitter like application which displays a lot of posts.
I want a user to be able to Like a single post, and when he does, the post will be displayed on his wall.
I want to display the post, a photo and a link.
Using C#, MVC, Where should I start?

Im using the Open Graph protocol to let users Like my website. How do I do it for a single post?

Thanks,
kruvi

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Do you want the user to "like" a post, and if so do you generate the post? or do you want to publish something on the user's wall?

Comment: Im using this code, but when my post is displayed in facebook only the link is displayed:
  <head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="My Title"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="MyURL"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="MyImg.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="My Description"/>
    ...
  </head>

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do it for a single post?

First of all, make that post accessible via a specific URL.

Comment: The post is accessible via a specific url. whats next?

Comment: Add the like button plugin for that URL, and give them also the option to post it to their wall as a link via your app.

Comment: The following code does post the Like to facebook, but what I see in facebook is only the URL of the post. I also want the Like to display an image and a text description. <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://MyServer.com/MySite/Post/@post.Id" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="90" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>